# Selenium-Webdriver, driver.findElement(...).getLocation is not a function, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to call .getLocation() on Selenium element like this code below.

```
const webdriver  = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.xxxx'))
        .getLocation()
        .then(l => {
           console.log('got a position');
           console.log(l);
        });
```

But i got

```
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: driver.findElement(...).getLocation is not a function
```

What did i do wrong?.
Or do i need to import some other librabry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `getLocation()` for `WebElement` in JavaScript. You have `getRect()`

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.xxxx')).getRect()
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks!, but do you know what can i use instead of getSize()?

Comment: @varis.dara `getRect()` returns `promise` with the coordinates and size `Promise<{height: number, width: number, x: number, y: number}`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot, Guy!